# Switching from Cloudinary to S3 - Unable to upload

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, cloudinary, keystonejs

I have a KeystoneJS project that will be switching from Cloudinary to S3. The project is working out of the box with Cloudinary. However, we would like to migrate over to using S3 for storage.

I currently have S3 set up in my `keystone.js` file:

```
var config = require('./config.json');

keystone.set('s3 config', { 
  bucket: config.s3.bucket, 
  key: config.s3.key, 
  secret: config.s3.secret 
});
```

I have another model called `Page` that I would like to upload images with. There is a field called `heroImage` which was previously a simple `{ type: Types.Cloudinary }`

However, in order for it to use S3, I had to change it to:

```
heroImage: {
  type: Types.S3File,
  format: function(item, file) {
    return '<img src="' + file.url + '" style="max-width: 300px">';
  }
}
```

When entering the AdminUI, everything looks fine. I am able to click `Upload File` and after pressing `Save`, I get a success message. I checked the S3 bucket with Transmit and found that the file was never uploaded. Additionally, going to the file URL shows this:

```
<Error>
<Code>PermanentRedirect</Code>
<Message>
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
</Message>
<Bucket>MY_BUCKET</Bucket>
<Endpoint>MY_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>
<RequestId>5CBD0F317C517254</RequestId>
<HostId>
VCoEc5PFevAecvyYC79ta7CIzWBewQ90kribJ59NAQ5JHn8dNEwMV+Ncv9cSfT1l
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Any help switching this from Cloudinary to S3 would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I simply had to remove any `.` from the S3 bucket name. For example, instead of `bucketname.com`, I just renamed it to `bucketnamecms`.